# Equilibrium distribution of relativistic boltzmann equation for diatomic molecule

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

We know that, in non-relativistic case, for Maxwell-Statistics, 
the local equilibrium distribution is like the following form
$$
C\exp\left(-\lambda_{1}|\vec{u}-\vec{U}|^2-\lambda_{2}\vec{\xi}^2\right),
$$
where $\vec{u}$ denotes the microscopic gas particle velocity, and $\vec{U}$ denotes the macroscopic velocity, and $\vec{\xi}$ denotes the internal variable.

In three dimension, $\vec{\xi}$ is zero-dimensional for monatomic molecule, and two-dimensional for diatomic molecule.

And in relativistic case, for monatomic molecule, 
the local equilibrium distribution is like the following form
$$
C\exp(-\lambda_{1}U_{\alpha}p^{\alpha}),
$$
where $p^{\alpha}$ denotes the momentum 4-vector of particle, and $\vec{U}$ denotes the macroscopic velocity 4-vector.

But what the internal variable and the local equilibrium distribution is like for diatomic molecule or polyatomic molecule?

Comment: Related:  [http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216819/59023](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216819/59023) and see [doi:10.5194/angeo-34-737-2016](http://www.ann-geophys.net/34/737/2016/)

Comment: As the aboove comment said,  the two links are local equilibrium distribution for monatomic molecule, and how about the one for diatomic molecule?

Comment: You would need to include spin (and maybe vibrational modes?) into the equation somehow, which is more symbol gymnastics than I have time with which to wrestle...  Technically, Treumann and Baumjohann's work only applies to protons because to deal with a relativistic electron distribution, one would need to include the particle spins which is not trivial.