# Why do velocities obey the Boltzmann distribution?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

So I know the Boltzmann distribution is:
$$
P\propto \exp \left(-E / k_BT \right)
$$

where $E$ is energy, $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is the temperature.  However, when we replace $E$ for the kinetic energy $1/2 mv^2$ and we get
$$
P \propto \exp \left(-mv^2 / 2k_BT \right) \, .
$$

This becomes the probability for a particular velocity $\mathbf{v}$, and not for all particles with a set kinetic energy.

Why is this?

Comment: I am slightly confused by your question. You use $E = \frac{1}{2}m\|\mathbf{v}\|^{2}$, and therefore your probability distribution is in terms of $\|\mathbf{v}\|$ and is in fact equivalent in every way to your initial Boltamann distribution, as all particles with velocity $\|\mathbf{v}\|$ have the same kinetic energy. Perhaps I have misunderstood what you are asking? :)

Comment: It becomes the probability for a particular velocity $v$ **and** a particular mass $m$

Answer (score 1):

> this becomes the probability for a particular velocity **v**, and not for all particles with a set kinetic energy.
>
> Why is this?

No, I think you are misunderstanding the initial formulation of the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution).  Your first version with $P \propto e^{-E/kT}$ is a probability as a function of variable kinetic energy, $E$, for each particle and a single, scalar temperature, $T$, for the entire distribution.

The second version with $P \propto e^{-m \ v^{2}/2kT}$ is a probability as a function of variable velocity, **v**, for each particle and a single, scalar temperature, $T$, for the entire distribution.

Thus, in both cases one has $P$ as a function of some variable that is specific to each particle (i.e., $E$ or **v**) and a scalar (i.e., $T$) that is related to the [full width at half max (FWHM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum) of the distribution.

**Side Notes:**

- Be careful not to confuse the velocity distribution with the speed distribution, as they have slightly different coefficients.
- Technically the conversion from kinetic energy should be done with momentum, not velocities but in the nonrelativistic limit this is a trivial issue.

Comment: But my book says speed is distributed by $v^2e^{-\frac{mv^2}{2k_bT}}$, this is a completely different function

Comment: Yes, that is what I point out in my **Side Notes** section.

Comment: ok, well why can you split this energy up into different components?

Comment: Kind of, but not really (i.e., be careful).  This is why I said one should deal with momenta, as energy is a scalar.  The completely general Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution is a geometric series for each degree of freedom and can have a different "temperature" for each degree of freedom (really a different thermal spread, not formal thermo temperature).

Comment: @TobyPeterken - You might find the following interesting:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216819/59023

Answer (score 0):

Because the formula depends on $v^2$, not $\vec{v}$, it's actually a probability for the particle to have a given *speed*.  However, there's only one speed for each kinetic energy, so it's really the same as the probability for the particle to have the corresponding kinetic energy.

The probability for a particle to have a given *velocity* is vastly smaller, because there are so many velocities with a given speed (the particle can be moving in a vast number of possible directions).

Comment: This is assuming a one-component gas, where all particles have the same mass. If there are two or more different kinds of particles, then there is no longer a bijection between speed and KE.

Comment: The speed distribution is not the same as the velocity distribution for realistic gas (e.g., 3 degrees of freedom).