# Kappa distribution function in plasma

Tags: plasma-physics

Does anybody know how to plot kappa distribution function in plasma physics (in Mathematica or Matlab)?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the "Plot[ K[x] , {x,-4,4}]"?

Comment: @peep no, i did it right now, but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the kappa function? If you're just asking how to operate the software then that is off topic as it isn't a question about physics.

Comment: john-rennie no my question is not related to the software. regardless of the program, i have problem in determining the function, physically speaking. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Please check my answer, I have a feeling it will not be what you want. Could you clarify exactly what is the problem? Also adding the reference for the picture would have been nice!

Comment: @peep  actually I compared this with my calculations and something seems to be wrong. 
I will add the reference here. 
https://munin.uit.no/bitstream/handle/10037/239/thesis.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y
pages 6-7

Comment: @peep Thank you so very much, I really appreciate that

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/216819/59023

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to reproduce the plot you've sent.
[image: plot]

Comment: Huber  Thank you so very much, I really appreciate that .

Comment: @lia consider accepting and upvoting the correct answer :)