# When can we say $x$ and $p$ are "independent variable", in order to find the Vlasov equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, variational-principle, plasma-physics, density-of-states

I have a question about "independent variable" in physics, and especially variable in Lagrangian or Density Function. I read several questions about it in this forum and although I have the feeling I understand the answer I still doubt.

## Introduction

Ok so I read, and maybe I understand and maybe I agree with the fact that in Lagrangian $L(q_i(t),\dot{q_i}(t),t)$ the variable $q_i(t)$ and $\dot{q_i}(t)$ are independant and are implicitly linked with $t$. When we impose the condition $\delta S = 0$ with $S$ the "Action", we link $q_i(t)$ and $\dot{q_i}(t)$ during the resolution of the least-action principle when we say $\delta (\dot{q_i}(t)) = \dot{(\delta q_i(t))}$ and later we can write what we we assume "since birth":

$$
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}q_i(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} = \dot{q_i}(t).
$$

Because a priori, there is no link between all the possible $q_i(t)$ and all the possible $\dot{q_i}(t)$ before that.

Don't hesitate to correct me at this point if I said horrible things.

## Vlasov Equation

So we move to the density function (in space phase) and I try to use the same argument in order to find the [Vlasov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlasov_equation). $N_p$ The

$$
  N_p \propto \iint_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(\vec{r},\vec{p},t) \, \mathrm{d}\vec{p} \, \mathrm{d}\vec{r} = \int_V f(\vec{r},\vec{p},t) \, \mathrm{d}V
$$

With $V$ the elementary volume in the phase space. If we want conserve this number in time we can say if we considere a flux in the phase space :

$$
  \dfrac{\mathrm{d}N_p}{\mathrm{d}t} = \int_V \partial{t}f \, \mathrm{d}V + \oint_S \vec{J_{\varphi}} \, \cdot \, \mathrm{d}S = 0
$$

with $\vec{J_{\varphi}} = f\vec{V_{\varphi}}$ and $\vec{V_{\varphi}} = (\dot{r_1},\dot{r_2},\dot{r_3},\dot{p_1},\dot{p_2},\dot{p_3})$ the speed vector of for each variable of the phase space. Ok so with the help of Green-Ostrogradsky we can write :

$$
\int_V \partial{t}f \, \mathrm{d}V + \oint_S \vec{J_{\varphi}} \, \cdot \, \mathrm{d}S = \int_V \partial{t}f + \nabla_{r_1,r_2,r_3,p_1,p_2,p_3} \cdot (f\vec{V_{\varphi}}) \, \mathrm{d}V
$$

With vector analysis we have:

$$
\nabla_{r_1,r_2,r_3,p_1,p_2,p_3} \, \cdot \, (f\vec{V_{\varphi}}) = f \nabla_{r_1,r_2,r_3,p_1,p_2,p_3} \, \cdot \, \vec{V_{\varphi}} + \vec{V_{\varphi}} \, \cdot \, \nabla_{r_1,r_2,r_3,p_1,p_2,p_3} f
$$

The difficult part for me is how we can justify properly that $p_i = \dot{r_i}$ is independent of $r_i$ and moreover $a_i = \dot{p_i}$ is independent of $p_i$.

I would say "Ok for $x_i$ and $p_i$ it's the same argument for Lagrangian part. There is a priori no link beetween theses variables moreover when the partial derivative on $x$ and $p$ impose to fix the time (no trajectories)".

For the case $p_i$ and $a_i$, in general physics give a explicite form for $a_i=F$. In classical electromagnetism:

$$
F \propto E + \dfrac{p}{m\gamma} \times B.
$$

What I feel: We can say $\partial_{p_i}a_i$ is zero because of the vectorial product. there is no $p_i$ on the $i$ axis.

Do you think I'm right? Is there more arguments? Can you help me to have a more elegant and right point of view?

## EDIT: Hamiltonian Point of View

In fact I read that if we use the "hamiltonian formalism" we found that the 6-current in the phase space admit 0 divergence: $\nabla \cdot \vec{V_{\varphi}} = 0$

We note:

$$
\nabla \cdot \vec{V_{\varphi}} = \dfrac{\partial \dot{q_i}}{\partial q_i} + \dfrac{\partial \dot{p_i}}{\partial p_i}
$$

We assume Einstein summation on the repeated indices. With the Hamiltonian equation:

$$
\dot{q_i} = +\dfrac{\partial H}{p_i} \quad \text{and} \quad
\dot{p_i} = -\dfrac{\partial H}{q_i}
$$

We get:

$$
\nabla \cdot \vec{V_{\varphi}} = \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial q_i \partial p_i} - \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial p_i \partial q_i} = 0
$$

So it seems that if we assume the Hamiltonian equation (because of the least action principle) it imply $\nabla \cdot \vec{V_{\varphi}} = 0$

Comment: FWIW, [Vlasov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlasov_equation) is a collisionless [Boltzmann equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation). 1. The dynamical variables are here distribution functions/[fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(physics)) $f({\bf r},{\bf p},t)$ of the phase space and time. 2. The position ${\bf r}$ and the momentum ${\bf p}$ are _not_ dynamical variables. They are merely _independent_ continuous labels of the fields. 3. The fields $f({\bf r},t)$ in the E&M sector are-independent-of/have-been-integrated-over the momentum ${\bf p}$.

Comment: I search for "collisionless Boltzmann" equation in order to have a maximum of answer on internet ^^ And they use often indeed the fact that $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{p}$ are not dynamically dependent, in the "same way" of Lagrangian first point. It is 2 axes along which the distribution function evolve. In fact it seems the only term we have to paid attention here is \vec{F} which is by definition linked to the acceleration \vec{a}, and in my case $vec{a}$ could depend explicitely of $\vec{v}$.

Comment: Btw  I have the sensation in fact "derivation" (eg in time) is not a sufficient "link" between "physical variable". This link appear because we impose a trajectory too quickly in our reasoning (in mine at least).

Comment: Somewhat to directly related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/300053/59023, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/177972/59023, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/257592/59023, and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/218643/59023.