# Pressure Tensor in Two-Fluid Equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, symmetry, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

I am reading through Fundamentals of Plasma Physics by Bellan and came across this definition of the pressure tensor:

[image]

I am wondering how the off-diagonal terms vanish in the case of an isotropic distribution, and how this can be shown mathematically.

Moreover, why would the integral of e.g. $v_x' v_y' f_\sigma dv'$ not be equal to 0 for an anisotropic distribution?

Comment: why "two-fluid"?

Comment: @Quillo - The two-fluid part is irrelevant here...

Answer (score 1):

I will first reference the following answer on how to define velocity moments of a velocity distribution function (VDF), $f\left( v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z} \right)$: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/218643/59023

We can also define a [Maxwellian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) VDF following the answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/257592/59023 as:
$$
\begin{align}
f\left( v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z} \right) & = f\left( v_{x} \right) \ f\left( v_{y} \right) \ f\left( v_{z} \right)  \tag{0a} \\
& = \prod_{ k = x,y,z } \ A_{k} \ e^{^{\displaystyle - \left( \frac{ v_{k} - v_{ok} }{ V_{Tk} } \right)^{2} }} \tag{0b}
\end{align}
$$
where the total normalization factor is given by:
$$
A_{x} \ A_{y} \ A_{z} \ = \frac{ n_{s} }{ \pi^{3/2} \ V_{Tx} \ V_{Ty} \ V_{Tz} } \tag{1}
$$
where $n_{s}$ is the number density [e.g., cm<sup>-3</sup>] of species $s$, $V_{Ts}$ is the thermal speed [e.g., km s<sup>-1</sup>], here the *most probable speed*, of species $s$, and $v_{ok}$ is the bulk flow drift velocity (i.e., first velocity moment) in the k<sup>th</sup> direction.

As discussed in the first link above, each factor of $v_{j}$ multiplied with $f\left( v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z} \right)$ in an integrand increases the order of the velocity moment.  So if we integrated $v_{x} \ f\left( v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z} \right)$ over all velocity space, we'd get $n_{s} \ v_{ox}$.  Since the integral of $f\left( v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z} \right)$ over all velocity space just returns $n_{s}$ (well this is how we define/construct the VDF so that the normalization parameter is such that this answer follows), then any constant times $f\left( v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z} \right)$ integrated over all velocity space just returns $n_{s}$ times that constant.

The pressure tensor is unique in that you do not multiply by the [dyad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics) $v_{j} \ v_{k}$.  Rather, you use what is called the *peculiar velocity*, where the k<sup>th</sup> vector component is defined as $\left( v_{k} - v_{ok} \right)$.  Since the distributive property applies here, we would be able to integrate each of these parts separately.  The second peculiar velocity vector component is pulled outside the k<sup>th</sup> vector component integral, so it doesn't matter.

Thus, we have the following:
$$
\begin{align}
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv_{z} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv_{y} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv_{x} \ v_{x} \ f\left( v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z} \right) & = n_{s} \ v_{ox}  \tag{2a} \\
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv_{z} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv_{y} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv_{x} \ v_{ox} \ f\left( v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z} \right) & = n_{s} \ v_{ox}  \tag{2b} \\
  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv_{z} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv_{y} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dv_{x} \ \left( v_{x} - v_{ox} \right) \ f\left( v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z} \right) & = 0  \tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Note that $v_{j}$ are abscissa of $f\left( v_{x}, v_{y}, v_{z} \right)$, not specific velocity vectors.  The solution shown in Equation 2c should make sense since the integrand is done over abscissa transformed ([Galilean transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation)) into a frame where distribution is at rest along that vector coordinate.  Suppose we multiply $\left( v_{y} - v_{oy} \right)$ to the integrand in Equation 2c, what then?  Well this factor would move outside of the $\int dv_{x}$ integral, i.e., it would not affect the results of that first integral.  Thus, the result is still zero.

As an aside, the off-diagonal terms in the pressure tensor, sometimes called the *strain tensor* or the *viscosity* terms, represent momentum transport across boundaries.  That is, the $P_{ij}$ term in the pressure tensor, where $i \neq j$, would represent mean momentum transport rate in the i<sup>th</sup> direction across the j<sup>th</sup> planar surface in a frame of reference moving at velocity $\mathbf{v}_{o}$.